# Index Out of Bounds Looping through WebElement List

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set web elements value to 0 or null. Basically i want to clear the value of the web element so it can store another element. Currently i get stack trace information saying : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1. I know that this mean that there is a value that is still there and it needed to be cleared before it can be used again.

basically i am trying to do this 
1 get list element value
2 loop
3 clear the value
4 repeat steps 1 -3 untill the condition is true and i break the loop.

my code is below. it works but only goes around 1 time.

```
 for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {

 String PreviewStatus = "//table[@id='cppProcessInfoTable_rows_table']//tr[@id='cppProcessInfoTable_row_0']/td[starts-with(@id,'cppProcessInfoTable_row_0_cell_2')]";
 List < WebElement > Status = driver.findElements(By.xpath(PreviewStatus));
 WebElement status = Status.get(x);
 String pstatus = status.getText().trim();


 String Status1 = "Completed";
 String Status2 = "Sucessfull";
 String Status3 = "Payroll Delayed";
 String Status4 = "Error";

 WebElement CalcPreviewPayroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'cppBatch_title')]"));

 if (CalcPreviewPayroll.isDisplayed() && pstatus.equals(Status1) || pstatus.equals(Status2) || pstatus.equals(Status3) || pstatus.equals(Status4)) {
  PS_OBJ_CycleData.Close(driver).click();
  break;
 }

 if (!CalcPreviewPayroll.isDisplayed()) {
  break;
 }
 System.out.println("\n" + "status " + pstatus);
 Status = null;

}       }
```

Comment: Should you change the following condition from   if (CalcPreviewPayroll.isDisplayed() && pstatus.equals(Status1) || pstatus.equals(Status2) || pstatus.equals(Status3) || pstatus.equals(Status4)) {      to     if ((CalcPreviewPayroll.isDisplayed() )&& (pstatus.equals(Status1) || pstatus.equals(Status2) || pstatus.equals(Status3) || pstatus.equals(Status4))) {

Comment: no because i want the first condition to be true all ways and either of the other four strings

Comment: the code is returning a string called (submitted) it neither of the 4 strings in the condition.

Comment: I don't know much about WebDriver and stuff but your basic looping seems wrong. Your pattern is always fetching you 1 record in the list, but then you have `.get(x)`. This is causing Index out of bound.
Moreover when your pattern is not dependent on x, why are calling this inside loop at all?

Comment: @Jonathan In which iteration it fails? Issue seems with line `WebElement status = Status.get(x);` as x could take value 0-99 ..and It might be your List `List < WebElement > Status = driver.findElements(By.xpath(PreviewStatus));` doesn't have value at that index.

Comment: I am thinking that x represents each iteration.. it seems your saying that the.get x is not needed as long as x >100 it will loop on its own is that what you are saying?

Comment: @GauravGenius my stack trace is saying line 380 which is what you said WebElement status = Status.get(x) is the problem

Comment: @GauravGenius and it fails going into the 2nd interation

Comment: @Jonathan correct...so can you confirm in which iteration it produces error, I mean for what value of `x` it fails?

Comment: the 1st iteration works when it goes into the 2nd it fails so the 2nd iteration fails.

Comment: @Jonathan Once confirm whether on the given xpath `String PreviewStatus = "//table[@id='cppProcessInfoTable_rows_table']//tr[@id='cppProcessInfoTable_row_0']/td[starts-with(@id,'cppProcessInfoTable_row_0_cell_2')]";` there are multiple elements ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167830/discussion-between-jonathan-and-gaurav-genius).

Comment: no it just one element that keeps changing or processing i am looping until text value equals Status 1-4 as shown in my post

Comment: @Jonathan then you don't need to use List here in this case

Comment: @GauravGenius I think MivaScott has the solution i should be doing foreach loop instead. I am trying this out i think it will work

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question, add it as a separate answer. It confuses what you were actually asking.

Comment: how do i add as a separate answer i have never done that before

Comment: nvm i found how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to restate what I think is your question. You will have to correct me if I misunderstood something.

You want to wait until a particular table cell contains one of the following values: "Completed", "Successful", "Payroll Delayed", "Error" and then do something.

In the future, it would be best if you started with an explanation of what you are attempting in words (not code) and then follow with the code you tried and the errors/issues with the code. It will help the readers see if perhaps there is another/better approach vs fixing your code.

The code below waits until the cell contains one of the desired strings. If that's never true, it will throw a timeout exception.

```
// store the status strings in a List (makes comparisons easier)
List<String> statuses = Arrays.asList("Completed", "Successful", "Payroll Delayed", "Error");
// define the locator (not required but since it is so long, it makes later lines more readable)
By statusLocator = By.xpath("//table[@id='cppProcessInfoTable_rows_table']//tr[@id='cppProcessInfoTable_row_0']/td[starts-with(@id,'cppProcessInfoTable_row_0_cell_2')]");
// custom wait... wait for the text in the element to be one of the supplied statuses
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
              status = driver.findElement(statusLocator, driver).getText();
              return statuses.stream().anyMatch(str -> str.trim().equals(status));
            } catch (Exception e) {
              return false;
            }
          }
    });
// if we got here, the element contained a desired status
PS_OBJ_CycleData.Close(driver).click();
```

Comment: That is correct thanks that was exactly what i was trying to explain you it it on the head.

Comment: JeffC thanks for this I will use it as an alternative. I found a solution thanks for (Miva Scott) though

Comment: Actually the answer i posted did not work as well as this one from @JeffC Your answer works better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to better explain what you're trying to accomplish as there is a lot of conflicting information:

- `Java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1` means you have an array with only one thing (Size: 1), but you are trying to access something outside of the array (Index: 1, but java is 0-indexed so in a one thing array the only index is 0).
- Your `PreviewStatus` xpath seems to be very specific: `'cppProcessInfoTable_row_0_cell_2'`. That makes me think you are only getting one specific cell, so therefore you will only ever have a 1-index array. The xpath should be generic enough to get a range of cells.
- You have a fixed for loop - 0 through 100. Based on the IndexOutOfBounds error, there aren't consistently 100 things to go through. It should be a loop based on whether or not the conditions you are looking for exist (`.size()` of an array for instance)
- Inside the loop you are are creating an array of WebElements. Generally you would only want to do this once outside of the loop and, as stated in the previous bullet point, looping specifically to the size of the array. Exception being if the `.click()` you're performing refreshes the screen. But that's a whole different ballgame.
- There is no real reason to zero or null out variables inside the loop as you are re-declaring them each time with fresh values.

The general flow should be something like:

- Get array of webelements
- Start a loop through array (foreach)
- Store the text of the text for the webelement
- If 'cppBatch_title' is not displayed, break out of the loop
- If 'cppBatch_title' is displayed, compare to known values.
- - If known, click something and break out of the loop
- - If unknown, print the text value
- loop

I still don't think this is what you're really trying for but it's a cleaner version of what you're currently attempting.

Comment: yes i am getting one specific cell that keeps changing so i am constantly checking to see if it reflects one on the status's 1-4 in my post.. so yes you are right i am look at one cell that constantly changing or processing after it processes it will be a status of 1 -4 as i explained above in my post

Comment: I will try the suggestion you have after your post (The general flow should be something like:) and see what happens

Comment: Okay, so you have one cell that keeps changing. First, getting it as an array is waste of resource. Second, what is you end goal? Do you keep checking it forever? What condition are you looking for that would allow the script to move forward? I think you need to start over an re-write the question explaining this better. Because as it, the answer is simple; you're trying to loop through an array that will only ever have one element.

Comment: the if statements that i have in my post will work fine is the equal one of them then it will break the forloop back into the one before it which is what i want. And yes i do want it to go one forever untill one of the status 1 -4 are met as i have in my code posting

Comment: I think your for each solution will work i have coded it and will get back to you in about 5 minutes.

Comment: in your above post that is what i am trying for

Comment: MIvaScott thanks for your help the for each solution worked very well and the close button was clicked and the loop broke which is what i wanted

Comment: MivaScott i posted the code that works i came up with based on your instructions thank you again a big shout out to you. I learned something today. How to think and what to think about.

Comment: @Jonathan - Glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says exactly what is wrong.  You are doing a findElements which returns an array of web elements.  It says in the error message that the returned size is one.  You're attempting to loop 100 times.  After the first iteration (zero) it attempts to get element one, which does not exist.  You should always check the size() of your returned array and use that as your counter limit.

Comment: I see what your saying however its like this (yes i am getting one specific cell that keeps changing so i am constantly checking to see if it reflects one on the status's 1-4 in my post.. so yes you are right i am look at one cell that constantly changing or processing after it processes it will be a status of 1 -4 as i explained above in my post)

Comment: Then instead of doing a .get(x) do an inner loop (if there's ever going to be more than one match) with a different index, or with a for...each, or  just use regular findElement (without the 's') in the first place.

Comment: I see now I'm pretty much just repeating what others have already brought up, so I'll stop unless there's some other way I can add to your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance what you said helped me but MivaScott helped me develop my own solution and it works i posted it above. i needed to do a for each loop instead of my original solution.